# Automating linux installation using preseeding

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, packer

In order to automate the installation of a Debian based Linux system, I use packer along with the "boot_command". Even if the question is not about packer, I want to give it a context.

Seemingly, some parameters have to be given in the "boot_command" (syslinux or commandline if you're not using packer) and these parameters cannot not be placed in the "preseed" file.

**Example for choosing the locale (working):**

boot_command :

`/install/vmlinuz initrd=/install/initrd.gz locale=en_US preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg --`

preseed.cfg :

**Example for choosing the locale (not working):**

boot_command :

`/install/vmlinuz initrd=/install/initrd.gz preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg --`

preseed.cfg :

`d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US`

The question is how can I only use the "preseed" file.

Comment: How did you check that `d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US` didn't work, since the default locale is English too ?

Comment: In the question I took the en_US example. I also tested with other locales and moreover this not a problem with only locales. It affects many other parameters as soon as the preseed is network based.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `auto=true` parameter to /install/vmlinuz. That worked for me, it seems to delay asking questions in the installer until later, which is when the preseed would be loaded. More info on that here: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs02.en.html#preseed-auto